# Как в JQuery плагине Select2 получать ответ от Laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel, select2

Пытаюсь прикрутить JQuery плагин [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) к [Laravel5](http://laravel.com/).

Роут для обращения через плагин:

```
Route::get('/tags/api', [
    'as' => 'api',
    'uses' => 'TagController@api'
]);
```

Метод для получения ответа от сервера:

```
public function api(Request $request)
{
    return Tag::where('title', 'LIKE', $request['term'])->lists('title','title');
}
```

**JS:**

```
$("#tags").select2({
    ajax: {
        tags: true,
        url: "/tags/api",
        dataType: 'json',
        processResults: function (data, params) {

            params.page = params.page || 1;

            return {
                results: data.items
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Как правильно спарсить ответ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Согласно представленному JS коду, роут `/api/tags` должен вернуть JSON массив с найденными элементами `items`, каждый из которых имеет два значения `id` и `text`:

```
public function api(Request $request)
{
    $tags = Tag::where('title', 'LIKE', $request['q'] . '%')->select('id', 'title AS text')->get();

    return [
        'items' => $tags->toArray(),
    ];
}
```